# VB.Net How do I change a WinForms button image at runtime

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a VSTO Excel Add-In that incorporates a dialog box containing a button which allows the user to toggle between a case sensitive search and a case insensitive search.  I have .png images which represent these different states CaseSensitive.png and CaseInsensitive.png when the user clicks on the button the button image should toggle between these, unfortunately nothing happens the image just remains the same.  Both png files have been added to the project and have had their build action set to resource.

I have found a number of posts on StackOverflow which propose a number of solutions to this issue, however none of the answers to these are working for me.  Here is the relevant code:

```
 Private Sub btnCaseSensitivity_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCaseSensitivity.Click
      'Toggle between case sensitive and case insensitive
      If Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive Then
           Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive = False
      Else
           Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive = True
      End If

      If Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive Then
           btnCaseSensitivity.Image = My.Resources.CaseSensitive
      Else
           btnCaseSensitivity.Image = My.Resources.CaseInsensitive
      End If

      btnCaseSensitivity.Refresh()

 End Sub
```

When stepped through in debug mode, the logic seems sound, however nothing happens.
From another post I have also picked up the following as a possible solution:

```
      If Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive Then
           btnCaseSensitivity.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("CaseSensitive.png")
      Else
           btnCaseSensitivity.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("CaseInSensitive.png")
      End If
```

However all that happens with this code implementation is that the button image disappears completely when toggled at runtime.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: In the first code sample, did autocomplete fill in the Resource names `CaseSensitive` and `CaseInsensitive` for you? Just to check that the compiler agrees with you on how to refer to them.

Comment: Oh, and do you have option strict set to on?

Comment: If you have trouble to change image in button. Simply draw 2 buttons with 2 images show and hide buttons where you want

Comment: Firstly, you can replace your first `If...Else` block with `Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive = Not Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive`. That's how you toggle a `Boolean`.

Comment: I would also replace the second `If...Else` block with an `If` operator: `btnCaseSensitivity.Image = If(Globals.ThisAddIn.CaseSensitive, My.Resources.CaseSensitive, My.Resources.CaseInsensitive)`. You should also be calling `btnCaseSensitivity.Image.Dispose()` before that to dispose the existing `Image`, given that you will be creating a new one.

Comment: As for the issue, are you displaying an `Image` on the `Button` by default? Can you display both resource `Images` properly that way?

Comment: Guys thanks for you comments, have taken them on board.   However as it turns out there was no issue, the code and image change were working fine, the issue was with the image, which was too large to show the border element (coloured green) which indicated that case sensitive was turned on.  Have now resized the image and all is working as intended, with revised code@jmcilhinney :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was no issue, the code and image change were working fine, the issue was with the image itself, which was too large to show the border element (coloured green) which indicated that case sensitive was turned on.  Have now resized the image and all is working as intended.